# Evaluating Jsweet for applet to HTML conversion

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, applet, jsweet

I have been evaluating Jsweet since the past 4 days in order to finalize a tool that can be used to modernize an application from applet to html5/js based front end. I have been able to try the trial examples where applet based java files are getting transpiled to .js files. As a next step I need to have Jsweet introduced to the an applet based application which has 9 tabs with considerable components like dashboards, report generation related drop downs, date picker elements, tables etc. However this application which I need to modernize is not maven based and hence does not have a pom.xml. It is executed using Tomcat.

1. Is maven a pre requisite for Jsweet?
2. My expectations from Jsweet are that if I am able to introduce Jsweet to my codebase like in the example and able to create a build using maven, I should be in a position to get .js files created in the target>js>applet folder. Could these be confirmed please?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider CheerpJ (https://leaningtech.com/cheerpj/) for this project. From your description it seems likely that the applet would work out-of-the-box.

If you want to give quickly give it a try: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein

Full disclosure: I am lead dev of CheerpJ and CTO of LeaningTech.

Comment: Hi Alex, We did evaluate CheerpJ as a tactical option to see if chrome could facilitate access to the applets based access beyond June 2022 (since IE would stop applet support post this time). Unfortunately, after adding the extension in chrome and accessing the url on chrome resulted in a blank screen. Any pointers in usage of CheerpJ which you could suggest are we missing any pre requistes?

Comment: Due to recent changes in Chrome Store policies CheerpJ Applet Runner cannot start automatically anymore. Did you click on the extension icon after visiting the page? For support you can find us here: https://gitter.im/leaningtech/cheerpj

Comment: Yes i did click and still the page was not rendered. On click of the extension, the square Leaning technologies banner was seen with 'Report bug' and 'Settings' buttons. It would be great if you could suggest  a workaround.

Comment: It is unfortunately not possible for me to guess what the problem might be. CheerpJ is used in production to run massive Swing applets and apps, so I have no doubt that your app can run as well.

If your applet is accessible on the Web, or you can otherwise give us access, we can take a look. If you prefer to contact us in private: info@leaningtech.com

Comment: Surely Alex. Shall reach out on this mail id.

Comment: I have shared an email to your specified mail id. Hope to connect with you on this.